Use Phaser.JS in Salesforce LWC
I have downloaded phaser.min.js from https://phaser.io/download/stable and uploaded inside static resource. I am trying to use it inside salesforce LWC component like following.
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
    import { loadScript } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';
    import PhaserJS from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/Phaser';
    
    export default class SimpleGame extends LightningElement {
        phaserInitialized = false;
    
        connectedCallback() {
            loadScript(this, PhaserJS)
                .then(() => {
                    this.phaserInitialized = true;
                    this.initializeGame();
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.error('Error loading Phaser', error);
                });
        }
    
        initializeGame() {
            if (!this.phaserInitialized) {
                console.error('Phaser is not loaded yet.');
                return;
            }
    
            // Phaser game configuration
            const config = {
                type: Phaser.AUTO,
                width: 800,
                height: 600,
                scene: {
                    preload: this.preload,
                    create: this.create
                }
            };
    
            // Create Phaser game instance
            const game = new Phaser.Game(config);
        }
    
        preload() {
            // Example preload function (optional)
            // You can preload assets like images, sounds, etc. here
        }
    
        create() {
            // Example create function
            // Add your game logic here
    
            // Display text
            const text = this.add.text(400, 300, 'Hello, Phaser!', {
                font: '32px Arial',
                fill: '#ffffff'
            });
            text.setOrigin(0.5);
        }
    }

But getting following error when I am loading the component, can anyone please advise.

